# Concise way to represent a list of dictionaries containing the same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a list of dictionaries containing the same keys but different values. The values for key `"A"` are stored into a variable called `animals_k`. Given this, I was wondering if there was a more concise way to represent the following:

```
animals_k = ['tiger', 'elephant', 'cow', 'goat']
animal_class = [{"A":"tiger", "B": 0, "C":20, "D":4},
                {"A":"elephant", "B": 60, "C":8, "D":9},
                {"A":"cow", "B": 0, "C":34, "D":12},
                {"A":"goat", "B": 43, "C":43, "D":44}]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it isn't very clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "concise"?

Comment: A more dynamic method that does not involve repetition of the keys

Comment: Again, it isn't clear what you mean. Do you mean *literally what you have to type as source code*?

Comment: Can you compute the values of "B", "C" and "D" given the animal?

Comment: @giucal no, those values are subject to change; they are not computed given the animal

Comment: I suppose you could create a skeletal `animal_class` with default values (say, `None`) and then fill those later programmatically. Comprehensions come to my mind; e.g.: `[{"A": a, "B": None, "C": None, "D": None} for a in animals_k]`

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "tiger": {
        "B": 60,
        "C": 0,
    },
    "dog": {
        "B": 100,
        "C": 12
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary containing a list of values for each key instead.

```
{
    "A": ["tiger", "elephant", ...],
    "B": [0, 60, ...],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code create the list using [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
animals_k = ['tiger', 'elephant', 'cow', 'goat']
animals_v = [(0,  20, 4), (60, 8,  9), (0,  34, 12), (43, 43, 44)]

temp = (dict(zip(('B','C','D'), values)) for values in animals_v)
animal_classes = [dict(**d1, **d2)
                    for d1, d2 in zip(({'A':animal} for animal in animals_k), temp)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(animal_classes, sort_dicts=False)
```

Result:

```
[{'A': 'tiger', 'B': 0, 'C': 20, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 'elephant', 'B': 60, 'C': 8, 'D': 9},
 {'A': 'cow', 'B': 0, 'C': 34, 'D': 12},
 {'A': 'goat', 'B': 43, 'C': 43, 'D': 44}]
```